# Jquery Sortable Revert on Invalid

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I want to acheive the functionality that one gets by using revert: "invalid" option in a draggable for a sortable jquery list.

I've tried many methods but none seem to work. It is the same code as the jquery sortable connected List demo . But what i want in it is the item that has been dragged out of the list should be reverted back to the original starting position .

I've tried using the beforeStop method in the initial sortable . But that does not seem to work.

I want functionality that looks like a draggable with revert: "invalid".

Sorry that I'm not posting code here.

Comment: As far as I can tell, that's [pretty much what it does already](https://jqueryui.com/sortable/#connect-lists). If you're talking about (partially?) disabling the hover functionality, I'd advise against that as it would become rather awkward to use. But I suppose you can do it with some combination of `start` and `out` events (possibly `over`, too)

Comment: If you can see in the demo there is an empty space left after the item being dragged is moved over the second List. So when we drop the dragged item outside the list it will drop the item into the second list. Rather what i want is the item to be reverted back to the first list.

Comment: Then you'll want to customise (disable?) the hover functionality. See second part of my comment above

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/p05e3czo/

This is my current implementation. When you drag an item out of sortable 1 into sortable 2 and then keep dragging it so that it is outside of both the sortable's  I dont want it to move to the second sortable and then move to the first. I rather want it to revert directly to the first sortable.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This issue was resolved by changing the revert status of the parent of the ui item in the over and out functions . This gives a smooth movement of the fractional parts when necessary . You can have a look at the fiddle below.

```
$(ui.item).parent().sortable("option","revert",true);
```

http://jsfiddle.net/siddharthpai/64y0bgfq/